# How do I download latest compatible version of an app?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, downgrade

So, I was trying to download PicsArt and it says that I need a 10.0 IOS version. And that's happenning to almost every awesome app and games in the App Store. And that's the problem, I almost can't download anymore because of that. Now, let's go to the question, How do I download the latest compatible version of an app that I haven't purchased before?

Please answer because I'm trying to download not just PicsArt but many more...

Comment: So what is the version of IOS you are trying to download with?

Comment: iOS 9.3.5, the last version compatible for iPad Mini 1st Gen Wifi

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your iOS version, if possible, or live without those apps.

[As of iOS 11](https://www.wired.com/story/the-ios-11-32-bit-appocalypse-isnt-actually-that-bad/), Apple has told developers they must update their apps to 64-bit.  Older, 32-bit, apps can't be on the App Store anymore.

If you're on any version older than iOS 11 and the developer hasn't updated their app (it's the developer's responsibility to do this, not Apple's), you will not be able to download or run the app.

Comment: So...I can't download the latest compatible version of an app anymore?

Comment: Not if it's a 32-bit app and hasn't been updated, Apple doesn't have it in the Store anymore.  If you don't have a local backup of the app then you can't download it again.

Comment: If you're going to downvote an answer, at least leave a comment saying why.  That could help improve the answer.

Comment: The PicsArt app is still in the App Store. Does downloading it on iTunes 12.6.3 and downloading it again at my iPad help?

Comment: @SkyGames if the version on the App Store requires ios 10 then it still won't run on your device. You can try it and see if it works but it's pretty old at this point.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's pretty old at this point"? Please clarify. If iTunes 12.6.3 is the subject of what you were saying, I want to ask you one thing, because there is a trick i watched on YouTube, What is the latest version of iTunes that still have the iTunes APP Store. Please answer.

Comment: iOS 9.3.5 is pretty old, that's what I was saying.  Since Apple required developers to move to 64-bit apps, it's more difficult to get downloads of the older 32-bit apps.  Some developers, like me, removed all 32-bit apps and they can't be downloaded if you wanted them.  Maybe this developer did the same thing. The developer determines the minimum iOS version for their app.  Did you contact them?

Comment: So, the versions of a 64-bit app when it's still was 32-bit is now gone?

Comment: It's difficult to say because it depends on the app developer.  If they still have 32-bit versions available then they might be able to tell you how to download it.  Most developers stopped supporting 32-bit once the 64-bit was made mandatory by Apple.